# SQL: Create a pivot table

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery, bq

I have a table that looks like the following:

| category | feature_a | feature_b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| top20 | 3 | 5 |
| top10 | 2 | 6 |
| top10 | 1 | 7 |
| top20 | 4 | 8 |

What I am trying to do is to create a pivot table that looks like the following:

| features | top20 | top10 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| feature_a | 7 | 3 |
| feature_b | 13 | 13 |

Each of the values in the second table is the sum of each feature per each category. I am reading the documentations on the pivot table [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms177410(v=sql.105)?redirectedfrom=MSDN), but it doesn't help me with what I need to get. Any idea how this can be achieved? (note: I don't have to use the "pivot" function, if it can be achieved by any other functions)

Comment: Please provide your solution attempts

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION` for merge 2 pivot tables like:

```
SELECT 
    'feature_a' "FEATURE", 
    SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'top10' THEN feature_a ELSE 0 END) "TOP10",
    SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'top20' THEN feature_a ELSE 0 END) "TOP20"
FROM bigdata
UNION
SELECT 
    'feature_b' "FEATURE", 
    SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'top10' THEN feature_b ELSE 0 END) "TOP10",
    SUM(CASE WHEN category = 'top20' THEN feature_b ELSE 0 END) "TOP20"
FROM bigdata;
```

[Pivot fiddle](https://sqlize.online/?phpses=&sqlses=f50bfb5ef272cfac60cd30d99fc4daa2&php_version=null&sql_version=psql14)

Answer (score 0):

Below is the way to go:

```
select * from (
  select * from your_table
  unpivot (value for features in (feature_a, feature_b))
)
pivot (sum(value) for category in ('top20', 'top10'))
```

If applied to sample data in y our question - the output is

[image]

Comment: have you tried? did it work for you?